# How to buffer two video sources and switch between them without any lag

Tags: node.js, http-live-streaming, video.js

Basically i need to switch between two video sources without any lag. It's like front and back video need to streamed simultaneously so that user can switch the view instantly. I am using videojs with hls streaming. What can be the best possible solution to achieve this.

Comment: You can have multiple video elements and switch between them.  This works, but can be problematic if the tab doesn't have focus as the browser is not great at letting your code run regularly, so the timing can be slightly off.  You may be able to insert content at a particular timestamp with MediaSource, by overlapping an existing spot.  I haven't experimented with this yet, or I'd post you a code sample.